# How to increase a text inputs height when the text overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a input field (a chat box) with a width of 300px. When a user is typing and exceeds the width of the text field, how can I increase the height of the text field so that the overflown text appears in a new line?

```
Here is the [jsfiddle][1]
```

Comment: Code/markup related to your question goes ***in your question***, not just linked. That's *why* Stack Overflow wouldn't let you post a jsFiddle link without posting code. The answer is to put the code in the question, not to mark up things that aren't code as though they were code.

Answer (score -1):

Use a textarea to achieve this, make sure in your css selector you have resize set to vertical.